# How To Filter Out Non Admin Accounts When Using Python Facebook SDK

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to use the Facebook Python SDK to access insights for marketing campaigns as described here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/read_objects.py

Being **admin** on an account is required to query at campaign level

The user making the call is only admin on some accounts. It throws an error if you try to call on an account on which the user is not an admin. Using this code:

```
me = User(fbid='me')

my_accounts_iterator = me.get_ad_accounts(fields=['id','name'])

for account in my_accounts_iterator:
    print(account.PermittedRoles)
```

How do I access the value of a subclass in python? The code above just prints the class name like this:

```
<class 'facebookads.adobjects.adaccount.AdAccount.PermittedRoles'>
<class 'facebookads.adobjects.adaccount.AdAccount.PermittedRoles'>
<class 'facebookads.adobjects.adaccount.AdAccount.PermittedRoles'>
```

The `adaccount` object (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/facebookads/adobjects/adaccount.py) has a definition for `PermittedRoles` that looks like this:

```
 class PermittedRoles:
    admin = 'ADMIN'
    general_user = 'GENERAL_USER'
    reports_only = 'REPORTS_ONLY'
    instagram_advertiser = 'INSTAGRAM_ADVERTISER'
    instagram_manager = 'INSTAGRAM_MANAGER'
    fb_employee_dso_advertiser = 'FB_EMPLOYEE_DSO_ADVERTISER'
```